# Shutdown 3 Guests at once in PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am running a script to shutdown all my VMs before taking a snapshot of them.  Currently the script only does 1 at a time...is it possible to up the number to 3?

```
$sleepTime = 5   
$maxWaitTime = 60

$vmNames1 = Import-Csv "C:\vmnames1.csv" -UseCulture | %{$_.vmName}

Get-VM -Name $vmNames1 | where {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | %{

# Guest shutdown
 if($_.Extensiondata.Guest.ToolsRunningStatus -ne "guestToolsNotRunning"){
    Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $_ -Confirm:$false
    $waitTime = 0
    while((Get-VM $_.Name).PowerState -ne "PoweredOff" -and $waitTime -lt $maxWaitTime){
        sleep $sleepTime
        $waitTime += $sleepTime
    }
    $line = $_.Name + " guest shutdown"
}

}
```

Comment: VMWare documentation says Shutdown-VMGuest accepts an array: `Shutdown-VMGuest [[-VM] <VirtualMachine[]>] [[-Server] <VIServer[]>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [<CommonParameters>] `

Comment: You could pipe that Get-VM statement into the `shutdown-vmguest` cmdlet, then you would need to modify the check on each of the VM's power states to ensure all three VMs show a status of 'PoweredOff'.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sleepTime = 5   
$maxWaitTime = 60

$vmnames = "vm1","vm2","vm3","vm4","vm5","vm6","vm7","vm8","vm9"
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $vmnames.count; $i += 3) {
   $threevms += ,@($vmnames[$i..($i+2)]);
}
foreach($v in $threevms){
    Get-VM -Name $v | where {$_.PowerState -eq "PoweredOn"} | %{
    # Guest shutdown
    if($_.Extensiondata.Guest.ToolsRunningStatus -ne "guestToolsNotRunning"){
            Shutdown-VMGuest -VM $_ -Confirm:$false
            $waitTime = 0
            while((Get-VM $_.Name).PowerState -ne "PoweredOff" -and $waitTime -lt $maxWaitTime){
                sleep $sleepTime
                $waitTime += $sleepTime
            }
            $line = $_.Name + " guest shutdown"
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned Get-VM will take a list.